# How can I start layoutAnimation when(before) leaving an activity

Tags: android, animation, back, layout-animation

I have a LinearLayout View in my activity.

When I press back button I want LinearLayout's children to slide out.

I have the following code which doesn't do anything:

```
private void SlideOut()
{
    LayoutAnimationController controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_animation_row_slide_out);
    Animation animation=controller.getAnimation();
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    LinearLayout menuLayout =((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuLayout));
    menuLayout.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    menuLayout.startLayoutAnimation();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    //super.onBackPressed();
    SlideOut();     
}
```

I have commented out super.OnBackPressed() to see if the animation starts, and it don't start.

Somebody with similar problems ?

Comment: SlideOut method is working when I'm calling it from a button onClick...

Answer (score 0):

check if SlideOut() is called in onBackPressed - i'm guessing your back press is being handled elsewhere - possibly by the virtual keyboard

Comment: I have checked it with a break point and it runs the SlideOut() method, but nothing occur.

Answer (score 0):

try this.it may help you:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
    SlideOut();
    return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

    //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

can u just change the code here here :

```
private void SlideOut()
{
    Animation controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_animation_row_slide_out);
   // Animation animation=controller.getAnimation();
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    LinearLayout menuLayout =((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuLayout));
    menuLayout.startAnimation(controller);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, still don't work and again, the method was called (tested with breakpoint)

Comment: SlideOut() method is called on a button onClick event and it's working

Comment: R.anim.layout_animation_row_slide_out is a LayoutAnimation, I must load it with loadLayoutAnimation, and I can't assign it to an Animation object.

Comment: Try it to implement inside onPause() method.let's see

Comment: Thanks anyway, I'm giving up for today :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be exiting the activity before animation is finished. Try implementing Animation Listener