# startLayoutAnimation not work in onBackPressed or OnKeyListener(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)

Tags: android, onbackpressed, layout-animation

I have a LinearLayout View in my activity.

When I press back button I want LinearLayout's children to slide out.

I have the following code which doesn't do anything:

```
private void SlideOut()
{
    LayoutAnimationController controller = 
    AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_pop_out);
    Animation animation=controller.getAnimation();
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    LinearLayout menuLayout =((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuLayout));
    menuLayout.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
    menuLayout.startLayoutAnimation();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    //super.onBackPressed();
    SlideOut();     
}
```

layout_pop_out is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:animationOrder="reverse"
                 android:animation="@anim/pop_out"
                 android:delay="10%" />
```

I have commented out super.OnBackPressed() to see if the animation starts, and it don't start.

Somebody with similar problems ?

**if set a onclick Listener in a button,  the method SlideOut can work,the animation play.** 
i think the problem is about "startLayoutAnimation", if call in onBackPressed or OnKeyListener(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) the layout-animation not play, but i click a button the animation paly.

```
 /**
     * Runs the layout animation. Calling this method triggers a relayout of
     * this view group.
     */
    public void startLayoutAnimation() {
        if (mLayoutAnimationController != null) {
            mGroupFlags |= FLAG_RUN_ANIMATION;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

[How can I start layoutAnimation when(before) leaving an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027572/how-can-i-start-layoutanimation-whenbefore-leaving-an-activity)

Comment: can you post xml have R.id.menuLayout

Comment: and layout_animation_row_slide_out.xml

Comment: i think the problem is about "startLayoutAnimation", if call in onBackPressed or OnKeyListener(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) the layout-animation not play, but i click a button the animation paly.

Comment: why you hide //super.onBackPressed();. This makes it not work

Comment: not hide it, the result is the same.  if change "layout-animation" to use view animation, the code run ok, so i want know call the "startLayoutAnimation" why not play animation , when call in onBackPressed or onKeyListener.

Comment: I also have the same problem and worked it out if i call requestLayout explicitly after calling startAnimation